# .find on jQuery giving me NaN

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a xml file .

The structure is

```
<library>
<book>
<title ISBN="12345">book title 1</title>
</book>
<book>
<title  ISBN="234567">book title 2</title>
</book>
......
</library>
```

I am trying the following code to put the titles somewhere in my html:

```
$(xml).find("book").each( function(){           
            $("#content0").append($(this).find("title").text();
        } );
```

It is only giving me NaN . What am I doing wrong? (other values from xml is showing fine)

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket after `text()`.

Comment: That should give a script error, not NaN. It should not even work at all.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What you want to get? Just the text? You should set the element text and not use `append`. That’s for appending new elements.

Comment: I am not getting an script error . Just NaN. 

Maybe missed a bracket while stripping things of my code. 

I am trying to get the text within <title></title>

Comment: @Prodip look at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_get.asp for this. there's an example function for this (using getElementsbyTagName)

Comment: Tip: Separate the expression to get the title element's text from the .append() call, and you'll get a better idea of what's going wrong. Keep breaking statements down, and logging as necessary, until you find more information about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `append` a text and not an element to `#content0`. Try setting the element `text` instead.

```
// set a variable to store all the <title> nodes texts, in an array you can join later
var text = [];

// for each node
$(xml).find("book").each(function(){

    // store the text
    text.push($(this).find("title").text());

});

// set the text with the desired spacer, in this case the spacer is ', '
$("#content0").text(text.join(', '));
```